# EventNotification in DocuSign SOAP based API

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, docusignapi

I am using EventNotification with DosuSign SOAP based API. The problem is i am not received any Request on the URL (that i mentioned in the definition of Event Notification) when any event occurs for Envelope.

Following are my code snippet: (here i required notification when envelope is completed)

```
Dim EnvelopeNotificationURL As String = "https://{my url}"

Dim EventNotifi As New EventNotification

EventNotifi.URL = EnvelopeNotificationURL

EventNotifi.LoggingEnabled = True 

'Defining Envelope Events
Dim envEvent(0) As EnvelopeEvent

envEvent(0) = New EnvelopeEvent

envEvent(0).EnvelopeEventStatusCode = EnvelopeEventStatusCode.Completed

EventNotifi.EnvelopeEvents = envEvent

NewEnvelope.EventNotification = EventNotifi

'// Here NewEnvelope is an instance of Envelope Class.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple of possibilities here:

1. The event notification portion of your XML Request isn't correct/complete.  I'd suggest that you update your question to include a trace of the complete XML Request that's being sent to the server (you can easily generate this trace using Fiddler or a similar tool), so that we can examine the full XML request and rule out any issues with its format/contents.
2. The XML Request format/contents is fine, and Connect is attempting to send the message to your listener when the Envelope is Completed, but there's an issue preventing the message from being delivered to your listener.  I'd suggest that you check the DocuSign Connect Logs (in the DocuSign web console) to determine: 1) if messages are being sent and 2) if there are issues with the message reaching the listener endpoint.  The Connect Service guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf) contains information about how to view the logs.

If you can update your question with information about what you're seeing in the Connect log file, and also include a trace of the full XML request that's going to the server, I'll update this answer with additional feedback.

Comment: i have resolve the issue.. there were some error in the XML that were build... Thankx..